# Implement passport-github strategy in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am implementing multi user composer rest server using passport-github.
All is working fine. But I've 2 different angular app running on 2 different ports.
Same as [this](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc) one but I want 2 client application.So basicaly, my successRedirect for COMPOSER_PROVIDERS should be different for both the angular app. 
Such that successRedirect should be redirected to the same calling port. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would think that you need to register a 2nd application in Github with a different callback url, and configure your 2nd REST server to use the 2nd ID and secret in the COMPOSER_PROVIDER variable.

Comment: Can't I have this done using a single Server?